# Восстановление документа

Tags: ms-word

Можно ли как-то восстановить Word документ, сохраненный, удалив содержимое?

Comment: сохраненый удалив содержимое?

шо?

Comment: Не юродствуй. =) Человек нажал Ctrl+a, ctrl+x и сохранил. Понятно же.

Comment: тогда ctrl+v остается =)

Comment: вот именно((((

Comment: Если после этого комп был выключен или перезабит буфер с выключенным офисом - не остается.

Comment: а нет ли программы с помошью которой можно востоновить его??

Comment: BadCopyPro разве что или аналог. Но она вряд ли поможет: Ворд очень неплохо затирает предыдущий документ.

Comment: ты же не файл с диска удалил, а буфер памяти ОЗУ почистил, НО если у тебя есть машина времени....

Comment: ребят у меня тут дело чуть по другому, я писал этот документ в течении месяца и сохранял его походу каждый раз. ну вот я думаю может там на диске сохранились какие то temp файлы..

Answer (score 1):

[Да.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827099)

```
 1. *.wbk 
 2. *.ASD 
 3. *.TMP
 2. ~*.*
```

Если среди этих файлов не будет вашего, шансов на спасение почти нет. :)